# Привязка FloatField к SlugField и его сортировка

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте.

Мне нужно привязать к каждому alias его рейтинг, что-бы потом выводить в шаблоне в прядке убывания. Как это можно сделать?

```
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Название товара', 
    default='')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    # image = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Картинка', default='')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='image/', verbose_name='Изображение')
    alias = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Alias товара', default='')
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Рейтинг')

def popular(request):
    title = 'Популярные'
    products = Items.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
    'products': products,
    'category': category,
    'title': title,
    }
    return render(request, 'popular/main.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все. Разобрался благодаря karthikr.

```
products = Items.objects.order_by('-rating')
```